# Codeingiter library multiple instances, not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, cart

Iam developing a codeigniter POS system project.

I have separate sections to product sale and product GRN. both are using **codeigniter cart library**

**in product sale section I created instance called : ocart**

```
$this->load->library('cart','','ocart');
$ocart = $this->ocart->contents();
$this->ocart->destroy();
$this->ocart->insert($data);
```

**product GRN section I created separate instance called : pcart**

```
$this->load->library('cart','','pcart');
$pcart = $this->pcart->contents();
$this->pcart->destroy();
$this->pcart->insert($data);
```

When Im going to add product to the cart in sale section, same time same product added to the product GRN cart also. and wise versa.

then I checked array contents using print_r($pcart) and print_r($ocart);

both giving same output

```
Array
(
    [6b913a2317d00f7bfa0abdaff1a1f67f] => Array
        (
            [rowid] => 6b913a2317d00f7bfa0abdaff1a1f67f
            [id] => 22020
            [pcode] => DS141
            [note] => PLATE
            [qty] => 20
            [price] => 1
            [name] => 97280
            [subtotal] => 20
        )

)
```

what is wrong with above code, please advice.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in method to destroy loaded library object.
You can do simply like that by using unset or setting null.

```
unset($this->my_library);
```

OR

```
$this->my_library = null;
```